# How to link a dropdown list to specific phrases?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm creating a dropdown list of names that are matching to the company. For example, this is the list:

| Name | Company |
| --- | --- |
| Name | Corresponding |
| Macfee-John | Macfee |
| Macfee- Jane | Macfee |
| Aventis- Doe | Aventis |
| ... | ... |

My plan is when I select the name from the dropdown list (E.g. Macfee-John), it will produce the Company name in the next coloumn.

Currently I have manually written a list of all the names and the company and used:

`=IFERROR(INDEX($Y$2:$Y$N, MATCH(C2, $X$2:$X$N, 0)), "")`

But, it keeps returning me a circular dependency error.

Does anyone know why this happens and what I can do to fix it ?

Comment: What do `$X$N` and `$Y$N` mean?  `$XN` and `$YN`? Something else?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.